# Matrix Analysis book for my research

Tags: matrices, book-recommendation

Since I need some knowledge from the matrix to do my research about control(like stability analysis), could you recommend me a good book about matrix analysis?

Comment: Maybe "Matrices: theory and applications" by D. Serre

Comment: Are you looking for something like this: http://www.math.rug.nl/~trentelman/psfiles/book_2005.pdf? If not, could you maybe specify the topic a bit further?

Comment: @Wizact   Actually, I need some matrix tools to analysis the maximum or minimum eigenvalues of a matrix, estimate the eigenvalues and so on ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two very good books I always recommend when it comes to matrix analysis: one is [Horn's book](https://www.cambridge.org/br/academic/subjects/mathematics/algebra/matrix-analysis-2nd-edition?format=PB&isbn=9780521548236) and the other is [Lancaster's book](https://www.elsevier.com/books/the-theory-of-matrices/lancaster/978-0-08-051908-1). There is a thrid book, which is also great but covers more specific topics on matrix theory such as Fourier analysis, circulant matrices etc: it's [Davis' book](http://Davis'%20book) on circulant matrices. Of course that you will find some very useful material on the internet, once this is a very vast and known area of mathematics.